# Cut video freezes for first 8 seconds

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I tried cutting my video using ffmpeg with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -ss 01:02:37.754 -map_chapters -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy -t 00:04:52.292 output.mkv
```

The only problem is the final video starts at second 8. The video just freezes before it.

My friend told me that the problem is on keyframe, as my video is h264 so it has very few keyframes.

Is there any other way to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend is right- `ffmpeg` only cuts at keyframes when doing a stream copy. If you transcode, you can do a frame-exact copy; for example:

```
$ ffmpeg -i source.mkv -ss 01:02:37.754 -map_chapters -1 -c:v libx264-c:a copy -crf 18 -t 00:04:52.292 output.mkv
```

Change the value for `crf` to suit your quality. Do note that since this is a transcode it will take much longer than a stream copy.

See the ffmpeg page on [Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) for more information.

Comment: That linked page says puting `-ss` before `-i` input flag can do the trick